# How to iterate through list of strings using regex in robot

Tags: regex, robotframework

```
*** Test Cases ***
find_lowercase
${values}              Create List        ${data[0]['top']['tshirt']}  
                       ...                ${data[0]['top']['shirt']}
                       ...                ${data[0]['top']['jacket']}
FOR    ${item}    IN    ${values}

log to console      ${data[0]['features']['0']}
```

Should Match Regexp    ${values}     ^[a-z]+

how do I iterate through the resulting string and check if the all strings in the list are lower case

Comment: Can you provide us with a [mcve]?

Comment: Only lowercase allowed in a string ? This `^[a-z]+$`

Answer (score 1):

`Should Match Regexp` takes a String, but you are trying to pass it a list of Strings.

You can use a `FOR` loop to check each value in your list.

```
${values}              Create List        ${data} ${data1} ${data2}
:FOR    ${item}    IN    ${values}
\    Should Match Regexp    ${item}    ^[a-z]+
\    Should Be Lowercase    ${item}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion to use for loops . could help in iterating through. I edited my question to reflect the ask

Comment: @NNNVVV You can use the `Should Be Lowercase` keyword. See edit.